# Regex - Delete all lines which don't contain a string? - Sublime Text

Tags: regex, string, lines

I am looking for a regular expression that can help me delete all lines in sublime text which don't contain .

For example:

I have a text file with domains:

`abc.com
def.com
ghi.com
com
jkl.com
com`

I would like to use a regular expression to remove all lines not containing .
So the result should be like:

`abc.com
def.com
ghi.com
jkl.com`

Thx in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 9):

Search for lines with no periods:

```
^[^.]*$\n
```

The regular expression means:

```
^      (match beginning of the line)
[^.]*  (look for any non-period character 0 or more times)
$      (match the end of the line)
\n     (match newline character)
```

Just replace those lines with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You needto search for a `regex` which describes the following:

1. Newline
2. 1 or more characters, none of which are a `.`
3. Newline (captured)

That `regex` is:

```
\n[^\.]+(\n)
```

After searching, you can then replace the `regex` above with

```
$1
```

which is the capture group (ie. a newline).